# How can I get the omitted results in R console

Tags: r

I have run a clustering algorithm in R which produces 271 clusters of my data set. On the console its showing only 4 groups. The rest of the results are showing as:

> + ... omitted several groups/vertices

I have tried options(max.print=1000000) but still its not working.
How can I get the rest of the results in the console or in another file?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since `cluster_edge_betweenness` returns a list, you can just ask for all its elements.

```
library(igraph)
n <- sample_pa(250)
x <- cluster_edge_betweenness(n)
str(x) # list
x[ 1:length(x) ]
```